# Create copy of string formatted as date

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I have a string that is formatted as YYYYMMDD - how can i make a copy in the format YYYY-MM-DD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// this is your original string
string _str = "20130101";

// you need to convert it to valid DateTime datatype
// so you can freely format the string to what you want
DateTime _date = DateTime.ParseExact(_str, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// converting to your desired format, which is now a string
string _dateStr = _date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

- [DateTime.ParseExact()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to parse the `DateTime`, then reformat it:

```
var input = ...
var inFormat = "yyyyMMdd";
var outFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(inFormat, input, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var output = date.ToString(outFormat);
```

Answer (score 1):

the safe approach is to convert it to DateTime Object , for example in .Net using below function :

```
  DateTime.TryParseExact()
```

and then using the DateTime Object you can format it again. like below example :

```
  dateTimeObject.ToString(YourFormatInString);
```

check MSDN for more details : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx